# How to build a SQL query from a list of selected fields?

Tags: php, mysql, database, query-builder, entity-attribute-value

I have an application that is programmed using PHP and MySQL for back end. Most of my tables are standard MySQL Innodb tables. Also, I have a feature where an admin can add custom attributes using [EAV model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)

I need to build a feature in the application where a user can create a custom view. Basically, I want to give the user a list of all available fields. The user can pick what fields he/she want to see on his/her screen and the system will create the query with the proper JOINS and display the results.

For example, if a user is looking to display field 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9. I will need to do the following steps

1. I will check what table each field belongs to.
2. Figure out which table name goes in the `FROM` part of the query
3. Figure out which table name goes in the `JOIN` part of the query if needed. and determine when fields go in the `ON` clause of of the `JOIN` statement.

The first step is fairly east to do, as it this info in stored in `entity_definitions` table "defined below"

The second step is also fairly easy, since I know which table is the base table so I can fill it out (ie. `accounts`).

"If needed" the third step is quite complex and I am not sure how to accomplish this. How would I know what table table to use for the Join and what column names do I use for the `ON` clause?

I tried to solve the problem by creating a table that has 2 columns one column for a the field name and another for foreign field name. However, I am still unable to build a query by just by looking at the selected field names..

To keep track of table/attributes definition, I created a table (ie. `entity_definitions`) that has a list of all the columns.

```
CREATE TABLE entity_definitions (
  entity_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  display_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  entity_key varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  entity_type enum('lookup','Integer','text','datetime','date') CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  object_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (entity_id),
  KEY object_id (object_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The `object_id` reference the table name where it belongs in the `entity_objects` table.

```
CREATE TABLE entity_objects (
  object_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  object_name varchar(60) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  object_description varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (object_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here is a [jFiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2a6e/2) that has the tables and some data/queries that I have done so far.

Question: How can I accomplish step #3? better ideas are welcome as well.

Comment: I think you would start with a UNION

Comment: @Strawberry why/how do I start with a UNION?

Comment: I'll rough out an example...

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following... although note that any further filtering would best be done on the annexe tables as the indexes on those tables will be unavailable to the superquery...

```
SELECT * from eav_core;
+----+--------+------------+----------+
| id | entity | attribute  | datatype |
+----+--------+------------+----------+
|  1 |      1 | start_date | DATE     |
|  2 |      1 | shift      | INTEGER  |
|  3 |      1 | station1   | VARCHAR  |
|  4 |      1 | station2   | VARCHAR  |
|  5 |      1 | station3   | VARCHAR  |
|  6 |      2 | start_date | DATE     |
|  7 |      2 | shift      | INTEGER  |
|  8 |      2 | station1   | VARCHAR  |
| 11 |      1 | end_date   | date     |
| 12 |      2 | end_date   | date     |
+----+--------+------------+----------+

SELECT * from eav_strings;
+--------+-----------+-------+
| entity | attribute | value | -- value = VARCHAR(50)
+--------+-----------+-------+
|      1 | station1  | Mark  |
|      1 | station2  | John  |
|      1 | station3  | Macy  |
|      2 | station1  | John  |
+--------+-----------+-------+

SELECT * from eav_dates;
+--------+------------+------------+
| entity | attribute  | value      | -- value = DATE
+--------+------------+------------+
|      1 | end_date   | 2015-05-09 |
|      1 | start_date | 2009-04-03 |
|      2 | end_date   | 2015-07-14 |
|      2 | start_date | 2009-04-04 |
+--------+------------+------------+

SELECT * from eav_integers;
+--------+-----------+-------+
| entity | attribute | value | -- value = INT
+--------+-----------+-------+
|      1 | shift     |     1 |
|      2 | shift     |     2 |
+--------+-----------+-------+

SELECT entity
     , MAX(CASE WHEN attribute = 'start_date' THEN value END) start_date
     , MAX(CASE WHEN attribute = 'end_date' THEN value END) end_date
     , MAX(CASE WHEN attribute = 'station1' THEN value END) station1
     , MAX(CASE WHEN attribute = 'station2' THEN value END) station2
     , MAX(CASE WHEN attribute = 'station3' THEN value END) station3
     , MAX(CASE WHEN attribute = 'shift' THEN value END) shift
  FROM
     (
       SELECT x.entity
            , x.attribute
            , y.value 
         FROM eav_core x 
         JOIN eav_dates y
           ON y.entity = x.entity 
          AND y.attribute = x.attribute 
        WHERE x.datatype = 'date'
        UNION ALL
       SELECT x.entity
            , x.attribute
            , y.value 
         FROM eav_core x 
         JOIN eav_integers y 
           ON y.entity = x.entity 
          AND y.attribute = x.attribute 
        WHERE x.datatype = 'integer'
        UNION ALL
       SELECT x.entity
            , x.attribute
            , y.value 
         FROM eav_core x 
         JOIN eav_strings y 
           ON y.entity = x.entity 
          AND y.attribute = x.attribute 
        WHERE x.datatype = 'varchar'
     ) n
 GROUP
    BY entity;
+--------+------------+------------+----------+----------+----------+-------+
| entity | start_date | end_date   | station1 | station2 | station3 | shift |
+--------+------------+------------+----------+----------+----------+-------+
|      1 | 2009-04-03 | 2015-05-09 | Mark     | John     | Macy     | 1     |
|      2 | 2009-04-04 | 2015-07-14 | John     | NULL     | NULL     | 2     |
+--------+------------+------------+----------+----------+----------+-------+
```

Comment: I am confused. I am trying to figure out how to build a query. I have a list of tables and list of fields. I am not trying to build an EVA model I am ready have that in place.

Comment: I obviously misunderstood the meaning of "better ideas are welcome as well."

Comment: I am looking for a better ideas to allow me to dynamically build a query using a list of fields

Comment: Ouch!  You have added complexity and inefficiency to already complex and inefficient "EAV" concept.